# What is the reason fo this difference in Facebook messages webhook JSON scheme?

Tags: facebook

I'm reading the Facebook Send API and events docs, and I'm surprised to see some examples define the message at the top level of the JSON object hierarchy (here for "text message")

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<PAGE_ID>"
  },
  "timestamp":1458692752478,
  "message":{
    "mid":"mid.1457764197618:41d102a3e1ae206a38",
    "text":"hello, world!",
    "quick_reply": {
      "payload": "<DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD>"
    }
  }
}
```

While others examples have a different object structure:

```
{
  "id": "682498302938465",
  "time": 1518479195594,
  "messaging": [
    {
      "sender": {
        "id": "<PSID>"
      },
      "recipient": {
        "id": "<PAGE_ID>"
      },
      "timestamp": 1518479195308,
      "message": {
        "mid": "mid.$cAAJdkrCd2ORnva8ErFhjGm0X_Q_c",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "type": "<image|video|audio|file>",
            "payload": {
              "url": "<ATTACHMENT_URL>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is seems like the object is the first example is instead contained in a `messaging` array. I can't find either what `id` corresponds to in this second example : there is no table detailing the fields on why the hierarchy is different here.

Finally, there is another example with a different structure:

```
{
    "object": "page",
    "entry": [
        {
            "id": "<PAGE_ID>",
            "time": 1583173667623,
            "messaging": [
                {
                    "sender": {
                        "id": "<PSID>"
                    },
                    "recipient": {
                        "id": "<PAGE_ID>"
                    },
                    "timestamp": 1583173666767,
                    "message": {
                        "mid": "m_toDnmD...",
                        "text": "This is where I want to go: https:\/\/youtu.be\/bbo_fZAjIhg",
                        "attachments": [
                            {
                                "type": "fallback",
                                "payload": {
                                    "url": "<ATTACHMENT_URL >",
                                    "title": "TAHITI - Heaven on Earth"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Are these differences documented elsewhere? Why do they exist in the first place? Why is `messaging` an array? Can it contain multiple messages at once?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events#format: _"All callbacks for the Messenger Platform have a common set of properties that provide information you will need to process and respond to input from people using your bot. In addition to the properties below, each event also has a set of specific properties that detail the event."_

Comment: The first one would be an example of what the content of a specific object inside the `messaging` array could look like.

Comment: _"Can it contain multiple messages at once?"_ - explicitly answered right here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events#entry

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! I had missed this section!